# Does Mercurial have an equivalent to git clean?

Tags: git, mercurial

hg clean does not seem to exist, which kinda bothers me. Is this a feature that Mercurial doesn't have or did they just name it differently?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `git clean` in the core Mercurial package.

However, the [`hg purge`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PurgeExtension) extension does what you are after.

There is an [open issue](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1665) to make this extension part of the core package.

Comment: The extension wiki page says "This extension is currently being distributed along with Mercurial.". I've had it installed since it was published .. I'm not sure _what_ version has or (will) introduce it.

Comment: Based on the issue tracker, it sounds like the feature was removed in v1.1.2 because "people that play with hg purge can delete files that they need".  The issue was last updated in May 2009, so it has gotten stale.  I would certainly vote to put it back in.

Comment: 1.1.2 ships it, not sure about previous versions.

Comment: Why not make `-n` the default, and require `-f` to actually delete files, like `git clean` does from some time?

Comment: And why not make it restricted to the current directory and below like `git clean`?  I got a nasty surprise the first time I ran `hg purge`.

Comment: Even though this extension is included, you still have to activate it before using it. It's as simple as creating a .hgrc file in your home directory (e.g. Win 7: c:\Users\(yourusername)\.hgrc ) and adding the following content:

[extensions]
purge =

Comment: Just for a tiny bit of extra clarity on @FrankGorman's comment, add `[extensions] purge =` to your `~/.hgrc` file.

Answer (score 12):

The extension is already included in mercurial, but you still have to activate it.

It's as simple as creating a .hgrc file in your home directory (e.g. Win 7: `C:\Users\«yourusername»\.hgrc`) and adding the following content to that file:

```
[extensions] 
purge =
```

(Home directory is `~/.hgrc` for most other desktop operating systems (Unix, Gnu/Linux, Mac osx, BSD, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

I don't use git for my repository management.  However, if I were to guess, I think `hg purge` might be what you are seeking.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a linux based system (or Windows cygwin) you can:

```
hg status | grep "^?" | xargs rm -rf
```

If this works you can put this in your ~/.hgrc:

```
[alias]
clean = !hg status | grep "^?" | xargs rm -rf
```

Then simply run:

```
hg clean
```

I tested this on windows using cygwin (should work on linux).

Comment: That doesn't cover files that are not tracked; git clean -fxd.

Comment: No need for grep. `clean = !hg status -un0 | xargs -0 rm`