# where can i find translation from git command to hg command?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git equivalents of most common Mercurial commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450348/git-equivalents-of-most-common-mercurial-commands)
>   [Git and Mercurial - Compare and Contrast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598759/git-and-mercurial-compare-and-contrast)

sometimes programmers are forced to learn lots of tools, some of them are usually very similar, so how to leverage the experience of one tool and make it less painful to start with new tools? it would be very nice if there is some comparation between the operations of these tools.

i have been using git for long time, but never used hg, i have heard that hg is similar to git, so i wonder if there is kind of translation from git command to hg command?

for example what is the hg command corresponding to git clean?

if there is such kind of translation, it would make git users to start hg more easily.

Comment: @EduardoCereto I don't think that one is a duplicate, though it does have a lot of good information.

Comment: @EduardoCereto  what is the hg command corresponding to git clean?

Comment: @hugemeow To answer your question [Does Mercurial have an equivalent to git clean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760283/does-mercurial-have-an-equivalent-to-git-clean?rq=1)

Comment: @R0MANARMY what about the corresponding hg command to git clean -xf ?

Comment: @hugemeow Not a clue, I don't use mercurial, just happened to have found that answer on google.  Perhaps if you are specifically looking for `git clean -xf` you should ask for it specifically.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for a mapping from git commands to those in mercurial, [this command equivalence table](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts#Command_equivalence_table) is a good place to start.